# How to parse this json in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have this 'json return' from node/express js but has problem parsing it. Needed some advice on how to do so.

Below is the json string i got.

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "comment": "wew",
      "published": 1388843496312,
      "username": "lol",
      "oauthID": "1234565"
    },
    {
      "oauthID": "1234565",
      "username": "lol2",
      "published": 1388843506898,
      "comment": "wew!!"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the code i used to parse this json but doenst work. This is the onSuccess function

```
success: function(data, status) {
    data = $.trim(data);
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(obj.comments);
}
```

Edit: This is my request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/loadcomments",
    data: {
        ytid: ytkvid
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, status) {
        data = $.trim(data);
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(obj.comments);
    }
});
```

I need to print out the values in json using a loop .

Thanks!

Comment: Show your entire request. Is it `dataType:"json"`? If so, then it'll be parsed for you automatically.

Comment: I think you don't need to parse it. you should learn to use `console.log`

Comment: try `alert(obj.comments[0].comment);`

Comment: @cookiemonster edit with my request...

Comment: If your response return json object, then you don't need parse it and you can work with with it as object

Comment: @daremachine: JSON always needs to be parsed. It doesn't have the ability to show up as JavaScript objects. However, jQuery under certain circumstances will parse it for you behind the scenes.

Comment: @Slay: If your response header is appropriately set as JSON data in the `Content-Type`, then jQuery also will parse it for you. Have you done `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @cookiemonster done it! i found the issue. It is this line of code  data = $.trim(data); .. removed it and i can parse the json. may i know why is that so?

Comment: @Slay: I'm guessing that jQuery is already parsing it for you, so you're passing the resulting object to `$.trim()`, which will actually convert it to a string like `"[object Object]"`. Since you did not include `dataType:"json"`, I'm guessing your `Content-Type` header is `application/json`, which causes jQuery to do this automatic parsing. I really think this jQuery auto-parsing behavior is unfortunate. But FWIW, you shouldn't need to `.trim()` JSON data. Formatting whitespace is ignored.

Comment: @cookiemonster thanks! you are spot on! solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specified that the ajax call is a json type, you don't to parse the string, you already will have an object.

In order to loop through all the comments, it would be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/loadcomments",
    data: {
        ytid: ytkvid
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, status) {
        var comments = data.comments, i = 0, len = comments.length;
        for (; i < len; i += 1) {
            console.log(comments[i].comment);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you can use $.each function instead for

Comment: Hi @mike i found out the problem. It is becos of this line data = $.trim(data); May i know why it works without it?

Comment: Because the data passed as argument is an object and not a string.  `$.trim` is used to remove whitespace at beginning and end of a text, and returns a string.

Comment: used @Krish R code snippet as it is more elegant! thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

```
$.each(obj.comments, function(index, value) {
   console.log(index+"::"+value);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: "/ajax/loadcomments",
data: {
    ytid: ytkvid
},
cache: false,
success: function(data, status) {
    alert(data.comments);
}
```

});